# IONIC Error: Could not find an "NgModule" decorator in app.module.ts

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am getting error while running this command in my ionic Project "npm run ionic:serve"

error:"Error: Could not find an "NgModule" decorator in
/Users/emblemtechnologies/Documents/ttgap/ttg-ionic/src/app/app.module.ts
Error: Could not find an "NgModule" decorator in /Users/emblemtechnologies/Documents/ttgap/ttg-ionic/src/app/app.module.ts
at new BuildError (/Users/emblemtechnologies/Documents/ttgap/ttg-ionic/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
at /Users/emblemtechnologies/Documents/ttgap/ttg-ionic/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/deep-linking.js:57:21"

it must run my app I am not even getting error in my code of App.module.ts file.
this is my App.module.ts file code:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version'
import { HockeyApp } from 'ionic-hockeyapp';
import { Push} from '@ionic-native/push/ngx';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { Diagnostic } from '@ionic-native/diagnostic/ngx';
import { CardIO } from '@ionic-native/card-io/ngx';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';
import { LaunchNavigator} from '@ionic-native/launch-navigator/ngx';
import { BackgroundGeolocation} from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation/ngx';
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx';
import { EmailComposer } from '@ionic-native/email-composer/ngx';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/mobile/Common/tabs/tabs';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/common/login/login';
import { SchedulesPage } from '../pages/mobile/Ticket/schedules/schedules';
import { UsersPage } from '../pages/mobile/User/users/users';
import { TicketsPage } from '../pages/mobile/Ticket/tickets/tickets';
import { FinancesPage } from '../pages/mobile/Finance/finances/finances';
import { TicketDetailPage } from '../pages/mobile/Ticket/ticket-detail/ticket-detail';
import { AddingServiceTicketPage } from '../pages/mobile/Setting/adding-service-ticket/adding-service-ticket';

import { ServicesProvider } from '../providers/services/services';
import {RequestInterceptor} from '../providers/authentication/authentication';
import {AddLocationPage} from "../pages/mobile/Common/add-location/add-location";
import {CancelTicketPopupPage} from "../pages/mobile/Ticket/cancel-ticket-popup/cancel-ticket-popup";
import {SettingsPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/settings/settings";
import {RemoveLocationPopupPage} from "../pages/mobile/Ticket/remove-location-popup/remove-location-popup";
import { CalendarModule } from 'angular-calendar';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {OverviewDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/overview-desktop/overview-desktop";
import {TicketsDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/tickets-desktop/tickets-desktop";
import {AddTicketDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/add-ticket-desktop/add-ticket-desktop";
import {FinancesDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/finances-desktop/finances-desktop";
import {Constants} from "../providers/constants";
import {AddNewCustomerPage} from "../pages/mobile/User/add-new-customer/add-new-customer";
import {AcceptQuotePopupPage} from "../pages/mobile/Quote/accept-quote-popup/accept-quote-popup";
import {DeclineQuotePopupPage} from "../pages/mobile/Quote/decline-quote-popup/decline-quote-popup";
import {ProfilePage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/profile/profile";
import {AccountDetailsPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/account-details/account-details";
import {CancelQuotePopupPage} from "../pages/mobile/Quote/cancel-quote-popup/cancel-quote-popup";
import {NewTicketDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/new-ticket-desktop/new-ticket-desktop";
import {TicketDetailDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/ticket-detail-desktop/ticket-detail-desktop";
import {QuotesDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/quotes-desktop/quotes-desktop";
import {QuotesDetailDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/quotes-detail-desktop/quotes-detail-desktop";
import {AddQuoteDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/add-quote-desktop/add-quote-desktop";
import {AddSkillPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/add-skill/add-skill";
import {SkillDetailPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/skill-detail/skill-detail";
import {AddNewCustomerDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/add-new-customer-desktop/add-new-customer-desktop";
import {ProfileDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/profile-desktop/profile-desktop";
import {AddSkillDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/add-skill-desktop/add-skill-desktop";
import {SkillDetailDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/skill-detail-desktop/skill-detail-desktop";
import {SettingPopupPage} from "../pages/desktop/setting-popup/setting-popup";
import {SettingsDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/settings-desktop/settings-desktop";
import {ScheduleDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/schedule-desktop/schedule-desktop";
import {AddUserPage} from "../pages/mobile/User/add-user/add-user";
import {SendInvitePopupPage} from "../pages/mobile/User/send-invite-popup/send-invite-popup";
import {ColleagueDetailPage} from "../pages/mobile/User/colleague-detail/colleague-detail";
import {SkillsPage} from "../pages/common/memberSignup/skills/skills";
import {ServiceAreaPage} from "../pages/common/memberSignup/service-area/service-area";
import {VerifyAddressPage} from "../pages/common/memberSignup/verify-address/verify-address";
import {WelcomePage} from "../pages/common/memberSignup/welcome/welcome";
import {AddNumberPage} from "../pages/common/customerSignup/add-number/add-number";
import {QuoteInfoPage} from "../pages/common/customerSignup/quote-info/quote-info";
import {VerifyQuotePage} from "../pages/common/customerSignup/verify-quote/verify-quote";
import {AddOfficeLocationPage} from "../pages/common/customerSignup/add-office-location/add-office-location";
import {GetOfficeLocationsPage} from "../pages/common/customerSignup/get-office-locations/get-office-locations";
import {ShowMessagePage} from "../pages/common/customerSignup/show-message/show-message";
import {TermsConditionsPage} from "../pages/common/terms-conditions/terms-conditions";
import {SignupPage} from "../pages/common/memberSignup/signup/signup";
import {UserDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/user-desktop/user-desktop";
import {AddUserDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/add-user-desktop/add-user-desktop";
import {ColleagueDetailDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/colleague-detail-desktop/colleague-detail-desktop";
import {EnrouteTicketPage} from "../pages/mobile/Ticket/enroute-ticket/enroute-ticket";
import {TimerTicketPage} from "../pages/mobile/Ticket/timer-ticket/timer-ticket";
import {UserDetailPage} from "../pages/mobile/User/user-detail/user-detail";
import {RefreshTokenProvider} from "../providers/refresh-token/refresh-token";
import {UserDetailDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/user-detail-desktop/user-detail-desktop";
import {EnrouteTicketDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/enroute-ticket-desktop/enroute-ticket-desktop";
import {TimerTicketDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/timer-ticket-desktop/timer-ticket-desktop";
import {InvoiceDetailPage} from "../pages/mobile/Finance/invoice-detail/invoice-detail";
import {EarningCalenderPage} from "../pages/mobile/Finance/earning-calender/earning-calender";
import {ChoiceSignupPage} from "../pages/common/choice-signup/choice-signup";
import {VerifyEmailPage} from "../pages/common/customerSignup/verify-email/verify-email";
import {CustomerLaunchPage} from "../pages/mobile/Common/customer-launch/customer-launch";
import {BlockTechPage} from "../pages/mobile/User/block-tech/block-tech";
import {BlockColleaguePage} from "../pages/mobile/User/block-colleague/block-colleague";
import {CompanyDetailPage} from "../pages/mobile/User/company-detail/company-detail";
import {QuoteCompanyPage} from "../pages/mobile/Quote/quote-company/quote-company";
import {QuoteGetSpecialRatesPage} from "../pages/mobile/Quote/quote-get-special-rates/quote-get-special-rates";
import {QuoteLocationPage} from "../pages/mobile/Quote/quote-location/quote-location";
import {QuoteServicesPage} from "../pages/mobile/Quote/quote-services/quote-services";
import {QuoteSetRatesPage} from "../pages/mobile/Quote/quote-set-rates/quote-set-rates";
import {QuoteSetSpecialRatesPage} from "../pages/mobile/Quote/quote-set-special-rates/quote-set-special-rates";
import {QuoteSummaryPage} from "../pages/mobile/Quote/quote-summary/quote-summary";
import {QuoteSupportContractPage} from "../pages/mobile/Quote/quote-support-contract/quote-support-contract";
import {QuotesPage} from "../pages/mobile/Quote/quotes/quotes";
import {QuotesDetailPage} from "../pages/mobile/Quote/quotes-detail/quotes-detail";
import {InvoiceDisputePage} from "../pages/mobile/Finance/invoice-dispute/invoice-dispute";
import {TicketAddressPage} from "../pages/mobile/Ticket/ticket-address/ticket-address";
import {TicketDesCredPage} from "../pages/mobile/Ticket/ticket-des-cred/ticket-des-cred";
import {TicketSelectCustomerPage} from "../pages/mobile/Ticket/ticket-select-customer/ticket-select-customer";
import {TicketServicePage} from "../pages/mobile/Ticket/ticket-service/ticket-service";
import {TicketSummaryPage} from "../pages/mobile/Ticket/ticket-summary/ticket-summary";
import {TicketTimePage} from "../pages/mobile/Ticket/ticket-time/ticket-time";
import {TicketTypePage} from "../pages/mobile/Ticket/ticket-type/ticket-type";
import {TicketSelectMemberPage} from "../pages/mobile/Ticket/ticket-select-member/ticket-select-member";
import {RatesPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/rates/rates";
import {RateAnalysisPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/rate-analysis/rate-analysis";
import {ServicesPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/services/services";
import {TicketRateReviewPage} from "../pages/mobile/Ticket/ticket-rate-review/ticket-rate-review";
import {TicketSearchPage} from "../pages/mobile/Ticket/ticket-search/ticket-search";
import {UserSearchPage} from "../pages/mobile/User/user-search/user-search";
import { CountryProvider } from '../providers/country/country';
import {InvoiceDetailDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/invoice-detail-desktop/invoice-detail-desktop";
import {CompanyDetailDesktopPage} from "../pages/desktop/company-detail-desktop/company-detail-desktop";
import {CompanyLocationsPage} from "../pages/mobile/User/company-locations/company-locations";
import {InviteMemberPage} from "../pages/mobile/User/invite-member/invite-member";
import {InviteMemberPopupPage} from "../pages/mobile/User/invite-member-popup/invite-member-popup";
import {MoveCustomersPage} from "../pages/mobile/User/move-customers/move-customers";
import {AddManualTimePage} from "../pages/mobile/Ticket/add-manual-time/add-manual-time";
import {MessagesPage} from "../pages/common/messages/messages";
import {AboutPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/about/about";
import {AppFeedbackPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/app-feedback/app-feedback";
import {DocumentsPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/documents/documents";
import {LegalPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/legal/legal";
import {NoticesPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/notices/notices";
import {ReportProblemPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/report-problem/report-problem";
import {ResourcesPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/resources/resources";
import {SupportPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/support/support";
import {StatusPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/status/status";
import {LicensesPage} from "../pages/mobile/Setting/licenses/licenses";
import {InvoiceAdjustPage} from "../pages/mobile/Finance/invoice-adjust/invoice-adjust";
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      MyApp,
      LoginPage,
      TicketsPage,
      TabsPage,
      TicketDetailPage,
      AddingServiceTicketPage,
      UsersPage,
      QuotesPage,
      QuotesDetailPage,
      SchedulesPage,
      FinancesPage,
      AddLocationPage,
      CancelTicketPopupPage,
      SettingsPage,
      RemoveLocationPopupPage,
      OverviewDesktopPage,
      TicketsDesktopPage,
      AddTicketDesktopPage,
      FinancesDesktopPage,
      AddNewCustomerPage,
      AcceptQuotePopupPage,
      DeclineQuotePopupPage,
      ProfilePage,
      AccountDetailsPage,
      CancelQuotePopupPage,
      NewTicketDesktopPage,
      SignupPage,
      TicketDetailDesktopPage,
      QuotesDesktopPage,
      QuotesDetailDesktopPage,
      AddQuoteDesktopPage,
      ShowMessagePage,
      AddSkillPage,
      SkillDetailPage,
      AddNewCustomerDesktopPage,
      ProfileDesktopPage,
      AddSkillDesktopPage,
      SkillDetailDesktopPage,
      SettingPopupPage,
      SettingsDesktopPage,
      ScheduleDesktopPage,
      AddUserPage,
      SendInvitePopupPage,
      ColleagueDetailPage,
      SkillsPage,
      ServiceAreaPage,
      TermsConditionsPage,
      VerifyAddressPage,
      WelcomePage,
      AddNumberPage,
      QuoteInfoPage,
      VerifyQuotePage,
      AddOfficeLocationPage,
      GetOfficeLocationsPage,
      UserDesktopPage,
      AddUserDesktopPage,
      ColleagueDetailDesktopPage,
      EnrouteTicketPage,
      TimerTicketPage,
      UserDetailPage,
      UserDetailDesktopPage,
      EnrouteTicketDesktopPage,
      TimerTicketDesktopPage,
      InvoiceDetailPage,
      EarningCalenderPage,
      ChoiceSignupPage,
      VerifyEmailPage,
      CustomerLaunchPage,
      BlockTechPage,
      BlockColleaguePage,
      CompanyDetailPage,
      QuoteCompanyPage,
      QuoteGetSpecialRatesPage,
      QuoteLocationPage,
      QuoteServicesPage,
      QuoteSetRatesPage,
      QuoteSetSpecialRatesPage,
      QuoteSummaryPage,
      QuoteSupportContractPage,
      InvoiceDisputePage,
      TicketAddressPage,
      TicketDesCredPage,
      TicketSelectCustomerPage,
      TicketServicePage,
      TicketSummaryPage,
      TicketTimePage,
      TicketTypePage,
      TicketSelectMemberPage,
      RatesPage,
      RateAnalysisPage,
      ServicesPage,
      TicketRateReviewPage,
      TicketSearchPage,
      UserSearchPage,
      InvoiceDetailDesktopPage,
      CompanyDetailDesktopPage,
      CompanyLocationsPage,
      InviteMemberPage,
      InviteMemberPopupPage,
      MoveCustomersPage,
      AddManualTimePage,
      MessagesPage,
      AboutPage,
      AppFeedbackPage,
      DocumentsPage,
      LegalPage,
      NoticesPage,
      ReportProblemPage,
      ResourcesPage,
      SupportPage,
      StatusPage,
      LicensesPage,
      InvoiceAdjustPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {mode: 'ios'}),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CalendarModule,
    NgbModule,
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage,
    TicketsPage,
    TabsPage,
    TicketDetailPage,
    AddingServiceTicketPage,
    UsersPage,
    QuotesPage,
    QuotesDetailPage,
    SchedulesPage,
    FinancesPage,
    AddLocationPage,
    CancelTicketPopupPage,
    SettingsPage,
    RemoveLocationPopupPage,
    OverviewDesktopPage,
    TicketsDesktopPage,
    AddTicketDesktopPage,
    FinancesDesktopPage,
    AddNewCustomerPage,
    AcceptQuotePopupPage,
    DeclineQuotePopupPage,
    ProfilePage,
    AccountDetailsPage,
    CancelQuotePopupPage,
    NewTicketDesktopPage,
    SignupPage,
    TicketDetailDesktopPage,
    QuotesDesktopPage,
    QuotesDetailDesktopPage,
    AddQuoteDesktopPage,
    ShowMessagePage,
    AddSkillPage,
    SkillDetailPage,
    AddNewCustomerDesktopPage,
    ProfileDesktopPage,
    AddSkillDesktopPage,
    SkillDetailDesktopPage,
    SettingPopupPage,
    SettingsDesktopPage,
    ScheduleDesktopPage,
    AddUserPage,
    SendInvitePopupPage,
    ColleagueDetailPage,
    SkillsPage,
    ServiceAreaPage,
    TermsConditionsPage,
    VerifyAddressPage,
    WelcomePage,
    AddNumberPage,
    QuoteInfoPage,
    VerifyQuotePage,
    AddOfficeLocationPage,
    GetOfficeLocationsPage,
    UserDesktopPage,
    AddUserDesktopPage,
    ColleagueDetailDesktopPage,
    EnrouteTicketPage,
    TimerTicketPage,
    UserDetailPage,
    UserDetailDesktopPage,
    EnrouteTicketDesktopPage,
    TimerTicketDesktopPage,
    InvoiceDetailPage,
    EarningCalenderPage,
    ChoiceSignupPage,
    VerifyEmailPage,
    CustomerLaunchPage,
    BlockTechPage,
    BlockColleaguePage,
    CompanyDetailPage,
    QuoteCompanyPage,
    QuoteGetSpecialRatesPage,
    QuoteLocationPage,
    QuoteServicesPage,
    QuoteSetRatesPage,
    QuoteSetSpecialRatesPage,
    QuoteSummaryPage,
    QuoteSupportContractPage,
    InvoiceDisputePage,
    TicketAddressPage,
    TicketDesCredPage,
    TicketSelectCustomerPage,
    TicketServicePage,
    TicketSummaryPage,
    TicketTimePage,
    TicketTypePage,
    TicketSelectMemberPage,
    RatesPage,
    RateAnalysisPage,
    ServicesPage,
    TicketRateReviewPage,
    TicketSearchPage,
    UserSearchPage,
    InvoiceDetailDesktopPage,
    CompanyDetailDesktopPage,
    CompanyLocationsPage,
    InviteMemberPage,
    InviteMemberPopupPage,
    MoveCustomersPage,
    AddManualTimePage,
    MessagesPage,
    AboutPage,
    AppFeedbackPage,
    DocumentsPage,
    LegalPage,
    NoticesPage,
    ReportProblemPage,
    ResourcesPage,
    SupportPage,
    StatusPage,
    LicensesPage,
    InvoiceAdjustPage,
    Subject
],
providers: [
  StatusBar,
  SplashScreen,
    InAppBrowser,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    Constants,
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: RequestInterceptor,
        multi: true
    },
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppVersion,
    HockeyApp,
    Push,
    Camera,
    Diagnostic,
    CardIO,
    Geolocation,
    RefreshTokenProvider,
    ServicesProvider,
    Network,
    LaunchNavigator,
    BackgroundGeolocation,
    AndroidPermissions,
    CountryProvider,
    CallNumber,
    EmailComposer,
    Observable,
    Subject
]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: You have imported Subject as entryComponent.

Comment: so I need to remove this?

Comment: yes. its not a component...

Comment: after removing getting same error

Comment: remove observable as well. they dont belong there, 
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs'; this as well.

Comment: Getting same error after removing those

Comment: Keep checking or commenting what are you importing. There are errors on what do you import and its impossible to get to know. Otherwise you create a stackblitz code  and share it